# Python TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'list'

Tags: python, list, python-3.7, comparison-operators

I want to compare a value to a list and if all of the values are True, return True.  If any values are False, return False. 
For example:

```
all(3 < [3,4,5])
```

Should return False.

```
all(3 < [4,5])
```

Should return True.  However, I get this error:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'list'
```

This runs:

```
3 < all([4,5])
```

but doesn't produce the right answer because 3 is greater than [True, True].  I apologize if this is a duplicate, but of the 6 examples I found of this error on SO, none of them answer my question.  The weird thing is I feel like I have successfully used this in the past without issues.  I am running Python 3.7.3 on a Macbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
all(3 < i for i in [4, 5])
```

`all` acts on a sequence of Booleans; it does not distribute over arbitrary arguments.  A search for a [tutorial](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/all) is usually a good idea before posting.

Comment: Thank you for confirming my suspicion. I really think this should be a built-in operation for comparison operators.  e.g. 3 < [4,5] should return [True, True] and 3 < [3,4] should return [False, True]

Comment: @DanGoodrick I disagree. Python is a general purpose programming language that is strongly typed. Comparison operations between distinct types should be an error.

Comment: You're welcome to propose that to the language standards committee.  Make sure that you follow the typing implications and implementation difficulties.

Comment: @ juanpa.arrivillaga I would agree in the case of strings, chars or other "vastly distinct" and inherently incomparable types.  But I would argue that a list is not vastly distinct from it's individual elements.

Comment: @Prune Do you know of a nice tutorial for learning about the implications and implementation difficulties?  My google search didn't turn anything up.

Comment: @DanGoodrick it is, in the general case. How could a `list` object not be distinct from it's individual elements? Unless you want to restrict it's elements to sequence types? In the specific domain of scientific computing, it makes sense for operations to be vectorized, but again, that is not python's specific domain. That's why there is a library that specializes in that.

Comment: @Prune I would like to modify my question, which you helped me realize is about comparison operators on lists but that would make your response not exactly coherent.  Do you mind?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga.  I need my list to operate like a list, not a numpy array.

Comment: @DanGoodrick you are trying to use it like a numpy array, though, so if that's not what you need, then don't try to use it that way.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - I need it to act dynamically like a list.  I could cast it back and forth but I would rather just use a comparison operator.

Comment: @DanGoodrick *why don't you just use your list like a list*?

Comment: I'm not sure if I know what you mean, but I ended up using the comprehension recommended by Prune.

Comment: I don't mind personally -- this is more about stability of Stack Overflow's archives.  If you need to substantively change the question, then a new question is generally warranted.  This one is about syntax of applying the `all` function to your list comparison.